# How to define component in Conan package

Tags: conan

My package contains several libraries ("a" and "b") and I try to define separate components. Like this

```
    def package_info(self):
      self.cpp_info.components["CA"].libs = ["a"]
      self.cpp_info.components["CB"].libs = ["b"]
```

Nothing special and according to documentation, I believe. But when I create the package, Conan says "ConanException: MyTest/0.1 package_info(): self.cpp_info.components cannot be used with self.cpp_info global values at the same time"

I do not understand that. What does it mean? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your example is correct, but your recipe is mixing the things and does not follow your example.

You ca not use `self.cpp_info.libs` and `self.cpp_info.components` together.

There is warning on documentation about [cpp-info](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#cpp-info).

Thus, you can use:

Or

```py
def package_info(self):
    self.cpp_info.libs = ["foo"]
```

Or

```py
def package_info(self):
    self.cpp_info.components["a"].libs = ["foo"]
```

But not mixed:

```py
def package_info(self):
    self.cpp_info.libs = ["bar"]
    self.cpp_info.components["a"].libs = ["foo"]
```

Comment: Where do you see I use "self.cpp_info.libs and self.cpp_info.components together" ? Am I blind?
There is nothing else in my package_info() method, only these two lines.
I do not show source()/build()/package() because they seem irrelevant.

And by the way, I do not understand that warning in documentation either. sorry about it.

Comment: Because your error message: "ConanException: MyTest/0.1 package_info(): self.cpp_info.components cannot be used with self.cpp_info global values at the same time". It only occurs when you are mixing both. Maybe your recipe is clear now, but you have a cached recipe with both. You can run `conan remove -y MyTest/0.1@` and build again.

Comment: Thank you for you help.